# What operation is causing this security exception?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm new to ASP.NET and IIS and I'm trying to determine how the different trust levels will impact my application. I've read several different guides on what trust levels are intended to accomplish but I'm not sure what's going on here. My goal is to grant least privilege, but anything lower than full trust produces an exception. The "high" trust level gives the following message:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

The stack trace is as follows:

> [SecurityException: Request failed.]
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type) +0
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName) +95
>      System.Type.GetType(String typeName) +61
>      System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerInfo.get_IsCodeDomProviderTypeValid() +14
>      System.Web.Compilation.CompilationUtil.GetRecompilationHash(CompilationSection ps) +2289
>      System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.get_RecompilationHash() +107
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDateInternal(Int64 cachedHash) +516
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CheckTopLevelFilesUpToDate(Int64 cachedHash) +57
>      System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +148
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +734

Does anyone know what operation is causing this?

Edit: Not a duplicate (as far as I can see). The type of exception in the other question is an `HttpAntiForgeryException`, with detail string:

> The anti-forgery token could not be decrypted. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that all machines are running the same version of ASP.NET Web Pages and that the  configuration specifies explicit encryption and validation keys. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster.

The exception I encountered is a `SecurityException` and the call stack differs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.\[HttpAntiForgeryException\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309374/an-unhandled-exception-was-generated-during-the-execution-of-the-current-web-req)

Comment: "I'm new to ASP.NET and IIS and I'm trying to determine how the different trust levels will impact my application." Say goodbye to that. Microsoft confirms partial trust won't give you any more security.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/2698981/asp-net-partial-trust-does-not-guarantee-application-isolation

Comment: Are you running in multiple versions of IIS, ex. debugging on IIS Express and deploying the app to a server and seeing different behavior? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295216/securityexception-thrown-on-deployment) question's answer might be of help.